# Disable submit button with setTimeout ( ) , Does it work?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, disable

I have a question if I disable form submit button for 5 minutes, after submission with setTimeout ( ) , does it work still even if the user reloads the page ? Or he/she will be able to submit again without waiting 5 minutes?
I want to avoid spamming.

I don't want to add captchas , since I m a newbie they seem so complicated to add into my existing working form

Comment: There is no way to really prevent it on the client. You can store it into local storage and see if it should be disabled, but the user can easily erase local storage.

Comment: What would you suggest me to do other than that ?

Comment: You can use localstorage to prevent it, but it is not secure. There is nothing secure unless you prevent it on the serverside.

Comment: When a page is loaded (or reloaded) all the code within it is re-parsed and run again. If you need to make sure that the time left is carried over to the reloaded page, you'll need to store it between page calls. This can be done with `localStorage` and stored, well, locally. If you need more security, you can store the remaining time left on the server, but that will require server-side code, such as PHP. 

Either way, you'll need to add some code that runs at page load that attempts to retrieve any time left to wait and starts the user off with that amount of time.

Comment: Anything you do on the client can be overridden by the user if they want to get around it.

Comment: How can I do kt? Can you suggest me a specific youtube search I should watch videos on for what you are talking about ?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing you can do to really prevent it on the clientside. You can use localstorage to hold it so when page reloads, you can disable the button.

```
function disableButton (time) {
  var btn = document.getElementById('yourButton');
  btn.disabled = true;
  window.setTimeout(function () {
   btn.disabled = false; 
  }, time);
}

function buttonClicked () {
    var enableTime = new Date().getTime() + 300000;
    disableButton(enableTime);
    window.localStorage.setItem('time', 300000);
}

var time = window.localStorage.getItem('time');
if (time) {
  var diff = new Date(time) - new Date().getTime();
  if (diff > 0) {
    disableButton(diff);
  }
}
```

The only really secure way to do it is serverside since the user can easily delete the localstorage or manually go in dev tools and enable the button.